# undefined method 'page_title_with_translations' in refinery cms

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, refinerycms

While clicking on **Add Link** in editor I am getting following error.

```
Rendered /home/amit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/refinerycms-pages-2.0.10/app/views/refinery/admin/pages_dialogs/link_to.html.erb within layouts/refinery/admin_dialog (61.3ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 187ms

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `page_title_with_translations' for #<#<Class:0xb1672e4>:0xb5e0730>):
    11:                 :rel => page_link.title,
    12:                 :class => 'page_link'
    13:               }.merge(link_args) do %>
    14:     <%= page_title_with_translations page_link %>
    15:     <%= page_meta_information page_link %>
    16:   <% end %>
    17: </li>
```

**Environment:**

```
ruby-1.9.3-p392
rails 3.2.13
refinerycms 2.0.10
```

**config/initializers/refinery/i18n.rb**

```
Refinery::I18n.configure do |config|
   config.enabled = true

   config.default_locale = :fi

   config.current_locale = :fi

   config.default_frontend_locale = :fi

   config.frontend_locales = :en, :fi

   config.locales = {:fi=>"Finish", :en=>"English"}
end
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Did you change the default language?

Comment: I have added i18n.rb. Is that something you are pointing?

Comment: When I built a website with refinery, I tried to change all the locales to `:es` and I had the same error. If you comment those lines, you don't have that problem, do you?

Comment: Still getting same error.

Comment: Did you restart the server?

Comment: Yes. Everytime I changed config, I restarted.

Comment: If you don't have important data, you can try to do `rake db:seed` to make refinery come back to the initial state.

Comment: getting ```Can't mass-assign protected attributes: slug```. seed.rb contains ```Refinery::Pages::Engine.load_seed``` line only

Comment: Fixed mass-assign security error. seeding success but still getting same error.

Comment: Try with `rake db:drop`, `rake db:create`, `rake db:migrate` and `rake db:seed` to reset completely the database.

Comment: Infact I tried same you suggest.

Comment: I surrender. Is it happening if you create a new refinery project from scratch?

Comment: No. It happens to existing project. I created new project and it works well. I am not sure if it is implemented correctly. I am new to refinery and need to dig dipper to fix it

Comment: The current version has overridden views, controller, models etc. I recently updated gems to 2.0.10. Earlier version was 2.0.8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to fix by overriding `Refinery::Admin::PagesDialogsController` of version 2.0.8 with  2.0.10.

Following line of `Refinery::Admin::PagesDialogsController` fixed problem

```
helper :'refinery/admin/pages'
```

Thanks @Pigueiras for being with me